# mongodb update/upsert and nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, upsert, mongodb-update

I have a collection that contains metrics about conferences and users on my website and I would like to store them by conference. Each conference has one or many users, and each user has one or many sessions, and each session has one or many metrics.

Here's an example of a conference document that I want to save :

```
{
    "conf":"conference12345",
    "users":[
        { //User 1
            "uid":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
            "sessions":[
                [// User 1 => session 1
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567891,
                        "br":"Chrome 92",
                        "os":"Windows",
                    },
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567899,
                        "bw":100
                    }
                ],
                [// User 1 => session 2
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567900,
                        "br":"Chrome 92",
                        "os":"Windows",
                    },
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567950,
                        "bw":500
                    }
                ],
            ]
        },
        { //User 2
            "uid":"2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9666",
            "sessions":[
                [// User 2 => session 1
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567891,
                        "br":"Chrome 90",
                        "os":"Mac",
                    },
                    {
                        "ts": 1234567899,
                        "bw":100
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to insert new data at once by using `db.collection.update` with `upsert` option. But I had a hard time figuring out how. Metrics should be added to the last element of "sessions" array.

Here's an example of data that I want to add :

```
// New user. a new document should be created because it's a new conference.
{ 
        "conf": "conferenceXYZ",
        "uid": "1cd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9512",
        "metrics": {
                "ts": 1234567891,
                "br":"Chrome 90",
                "os":"Mac",
        }
}

// Existing user. metrics should be added to his last session
{ 
        "conf": "conference12345",
        "uid": "2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
        "metrics": {
                "ts": 1234567891,
                "bw":356
        }
}
```

I tried to use update with upsert option but it's a difficult to find the missing pieces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- first filter/`$set` is to put your data
- checks if new user (its new user in case upsert or user not found)
- if new user pushes the new user
  else finds the user and adds the new session

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233ef04f7e3c64c6511e14a)

```js
update(
{"conf": "conference12345"},
[{"$set": 
   {"uid": "2dd8b4e3-9dcd-4da6-bc36-aa0988dc9642",
    "usession": [{"ts": 1234567891, "bw": 356}]}},
 {"$set": 
   {"new-user": 
     {"$eq": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": {"$cond": ["$users", "$users", []]},
            "as": "u",
            "cond": {"$eq": ["$$u.uid", "$uid"]}}},
         []]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"users": 
     {"$cond": 
       ["$new-user",
         {"$concatArrays": 
           [{"$cond": [{"$isArray": ["$users"]}, "$users", []]},
             [{"uid": "$uid", "sessions": ["$usession"]}]]},
         {"$map": 
           {"input": "$users",
            "as": "u",
            "in": 
             {"$cond": 
               [{"$eq": ["$$u.uid", "$uid"]},
                 {"$mergeObjects": 
                   ["$$u",
                     {"sessions": 
                       {"$concatArrays": ["$$u.sessions", ["$usession"]]}}]},
                "$$u"]}}}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["uid", "usession", "new-user"]}],
{"upsert": true, "multi": true})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This query should be slightly edited to add the metrics in the last element of `sessions` array. A new session element should be created if the metrics object contains `br` and `os` elements

Comment: the query above, always adds the new metrics object in the sessions array. It never merges with existing metrict, you want to update existing metrics also? based on what creteria? same `ts`? Its best to write all the cases and what you want to happen in each case, i wrote the cases that the query examines, expand those cases if you have more cases.

Comment: Thank you for the taking time to consider this issue. Here's my modification https://mongoplayground.net/p/ghiWD3Cm2wy. a new metric must go into the last array of sessions unless the metric contains `br` which means a new array should be created in sessions array

Comment: i added one more case, if `br` to create new array else push it in the last session. hope this time to work for you, query is big, but its simple JSON makes it harder to read but ok

Comment: This is a great job. Thank you